# ERROR: Application not supported by 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack

Tags: node.js, heroku

I type:

```
git push heroku master
```

and I get:

[image]
[image]

The file package.json is present [here](https://github.com/IvanDerlich/space-shooter-game/blob/setup-project/package.json)

I've tried:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
```

And I still get the error.

[This](https://github.com/IvanDerlich/space-shooter-game/tree/setup-project) is the repo branch.

Answer (score 2):

```
git push heroku [local branch name]:master
```

If I don't specify the local branch name. Heroku will automatically deploy from local master. That branch doesn't have a package.json file. That's why I got the error.

Comment: thank you for this answer. it had hard time trying to understand why it wont work